# Android Palette API filter out white and black shades

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, palette

The Android Palette class is useful to extract colors from an image but I have a special requirement.  The colors I extract can't be whites or blacks (varying shades).

How can I filter out the returned colors to ensure they aren't whites or blacks?

Note: I would replace the filtered out colors with a predefined grey.

Edit:  I know I can use Palette.Filter but I'm not sure how to go about getting a range of colors that apply

Comment: Check out the plaid app on [Github](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid). ColorUtils class might help you.